# Bootstrap aligment issue

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to align some elements with bootstrap but I have strange gap between them. May I ask you for some advice ?
here is the final picture of the layout structure.

[image]

Here is my code until this moment

```html
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
   
<section class="product-list">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="catalog">
          <ul class="catalog-list">
            <li>
              <a href="#">
                <img src="https://s23.postimg.org/mjrt9w557/example.jpg" width="260" height="260" title="someText" alt="someText">
              </a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- catalog -->
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="catalog">
          <ul class="catalog-list">
            <li>
              <a href="#">
                <img src="https://s23.postimg.org/mjrt9w557/example.jpg" width="260" height="260" title="someText" alt="someText">
              </a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- catalog -->
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="laptops">
          <img src="https://s27.postimg.org/ottosbaw3/example2.jpg" width="548" height="545" title="someText" alt="someText">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- row -->
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <ul class="catalog-list">
          <li>
            <a href="#">
              <img src="https://s23.postimg.org/mjrt9w557/example.jpg" width="260" height="260" title="someText" alt="someText">
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <ul class="catalog-list">
          <li>
            <a href="#">
              <img src="https://s23.postimg.org/mjrt9w557/example.jpg" width="260" height="260" title="someText" alt="someText">
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- row -->
  </div>
  <!-- container -->
</section>
<!-- product-list -->
```

Comment: Most browsers and frameworks have style presets. A good way to see this is using Developer Tools (Chrome, Firefox) on the Elements -> Styles tab you can see a rectangle with margin, border and padding to any element you hover. This way you'll se exactly what element is adding an unwanted style. Many people use Reset CSS to clear all preset-style before coding to avoid these surprises.

Comment: You want the blue squares to touch, without any gaps?

Comment: I want blue squares to stay like those on the picture provided and the big one to be on the right side but i'am kinda confused by this all columns and rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming I understood you correctly, you had too much going on with your `html`. There is absolutely no need to wrap individual images into lists.

View in full-screen, I did not add small display classes.

```css
.margin{margin-bottom: 25px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
   
<section class="product-list">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="row margin">
      <div class="col-md-6">
              <a href="#">
                <img src="https://s23.postimg.org/mjrt9w557/example.jpg" width="260" height="260" title="someText" alt="someText">
              </a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
              <a href="#">
                <img src="https://s23.postimg.org/mjrt9w557/example.jpg" width="260" height="260" title="someText" alt="someText">
              </a>
      </div>
          </div>
        <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
              <a href="#">
                <img src="https://s23.postimg.org/mjrt9w557/example.jpg" width="260" height="260" title="someText" alt="someText">
              </a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
              <a href="#">
                <img src="https://s23.postimg.org/mjrt9w557/example.jpg" width="260" height="260" title="someText" alt="someText">
              </a>
      </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="laptops">
          <img src="https://s27.postimg.org/ottosbaw3/example2.jpg" width="548" height="545" title="someText" alt="someText">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- container -->
</section>
<!-- product-list -->
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correct you are wondering about the gap between the elements. Bootstrap applies padding between columns called **gutter**. You might have to adjust your gutter padding and margins if you do not want a gap between your columns.

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-options

Comment: yes I am wondering about the gap between my first two blue boxes and second blue boxes which are way under the first ones.

Comment: Which ones do you mean? The gutter between column 1 and column 2 appears to be the same size as the gutter between column 2 and column 3.

Answer (score 0):

Use two col-md-6 and inside the first col-md-6 use 4 col-md-6 with specific height and your problem is solved.